# how to add break tag inside description tag in kml file using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, kml

I really want to add a *break* tag inside the *description* tag through python 2.7 script. I tried by putting direct tag inside the description string.

Every time i gives a *break* tag the output in the *description* tag will be like this

```html
&lt;br&gt;
```

I need to get a break tag like below in kml

```
<br/>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you adding the `<br/>`?  What does your KML look like (a snippet that exhibits the issue)?  Are you sure whatever tool you are using to create the KML isn't double escaping it?

Comment: **description='http://%s <br/> http://%s  <br/> %s'%(IP1,IP2,line_tblUnit[index_tblUnit][5])**

description look like this... Kml file is creating during the program using simpleKml module. I am not sure about double escaping.

Comment: _<description>http://192.168.1.20 &lt;br/&gt; http:// &lt;br/&gt; 21 queen street</description>_

this is the kml output

Comment: Please edit your question to include the information (you can't really format it so it is readable in the comments).